# Specifying an instance variable from the method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a project that will offer multiple trivia games using Rails. There is a table of questions and answers, all of which are classified as a type of quiz through a column for category (in order to specify question type, like "sports" vs. "history").

To command the question/answer combos, I call in the trivia.html.erb file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     new Questions().init();
     })
 </script>
```

So we call the Questions model, but I only want to show one category of questions to the user at a time. When I load the sports game, I want to show questions with the category "sports" in the Questions table. Likewise, I want to show "history" questions when we the user chooses history. I do not want to show multiple categories at the same time.

In my quiz_controller.rb, I know I can designate a single category with an instance variable, like this:

```
 module API
 class QuizController < ::ApplicationController
    def start


  @participation = current_user.participations.create(category: 'history')
end

def show_question
  if current_question.nil?
    participation.update finished: true
    render json: { finished: true }
  end
end

def validate_answer
  result = current_question.correcta == params[:answer].to_i

  participation.increment! :current_question_index
  participation.increment! :score if result

  render json: { result: result }
end

def skip_question
  participation.increment! :current_question_index
  render json: {}
end

private

def participation
  @participation = current_user.participations.where(
    finished: false,
    id: params[:participation_id]
  ).first
end

def current_question
  @current_question = History
    .where(category: participation.category)
    .order(id: :asc)[participation.current_question_index]
    end
  end
 end
```

As a result, this would show only questions that have a matching "history" category. But since I want to run multiple quizzes from the same controller, what if I added a second instance variable for:

```
 @participation = current_user.participations.create(category: 'history')
 @participation = current_user.participations.create(category: 'sports')
```

With two instance variables (or more, let's say I have five quiz categories), can I specify an instance from the `new Questions().init();` command in the html.erb file? Or do I need to create multiple Quiz Controllers (like history vs. sports) and then call them separately when the user generates the quiz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would not be DRY ("do not repeat yourself") to create multiple controllers. Since you intend to let the user to select a category like sports or history, you can extract this category from the `params` and use it in the controller. If you want to use the seleteced category for multiple subsequent requests (without letting the user to re-select it each time), you could store it e.g. in a cookie - this is done with

`session[:category] = params[:category]`